# How android ROMS based on TouchWiz work if TouchWiz source code is not available as opensource?

Tags: android, samsung-touchwiz

Source code of samsung-touchwiz is not available to public to download and use. But there are custom roms which have touchwiz UI available .How do touch-wiz based roms like Salman rom work without having samsung touch-wiz code?

Answer (score 3):

TouchWiz gets shipped as an *.APK on Samsung Smartphones. So  if you want to integrate the TouchWizUI, you just have to integrate the APK into your rom and voila, you got a touchWiz based android rom.

Edit: Maybe you'll need to integrate the framework-res.apk also to keep the style consistent.